# How do I trigger an event listener when clicking on only an image?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Currently I have a div element that contains two(+) images. One image has a z-index of 1, and is behind the other. I want to trigger an event listener when you click on only the first image.

When I click on the smaller image with a z-index of 2, the event listener of the z-index 1 image occurs.
link to site: hi2.aisliniscool.repl.co
relevant JS code:

```
const champDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const champImg = document.createElement('img'); //(z-index 1)
    const favButton = document.createElement('img');
    champDiv.addEventListener('click', toggleDiv);
    favButton.addEventListener('click', favoriteChamp); //(z-index 2)
    favButton.addEventListener('click', setCookie);
    favButton.src = "/ext/icons/transparent.png";
    favButton.classList.add('favButton');
    champDiv.classList.add('champdiv');
    champImg.classList.add('champion');
```

If I click on favButton, toggleDiv and favoriteChamp executes, but I only want favoriteChamp to execute.

Comment: Looks like you attached two event listeners to  "favButton". Not sure if this was what you wanted. Maybe one of the even listeners should be attached to "champImg" instead. If yes please edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of bubbling.

You need to stop the parents' events from triggering when you trigger their child event.

You are either gonna need this:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

or this:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

To fully comprehend what's going and how to handle propagation you can read the following:

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-propagation-event-bubbling-event-catching-beginners-guide/